# Create a gradient that aligns with the camera

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create a gradient that aligns with the camera so that everything behind the camera is black/null. If you can somehow manage to make it a cone, even better. But a simple horizontal gradient will work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Somehow I can smell here what you actually want to do ...because why should any objects disappear somewhere if they are not visible?

I therefore assume that you really only want to create instances there that are in the camera's field of view.

If I have smelled correctly, you can achieve this in the following way:

1. First, create a cube that you transform so that it maps the camera frustrum.

   [image]
2. Then use the node `Mesh Boolean` and create an intersection of these two shapes from the simplified plane and the frustum.

   [image]
3. If you then apply the node `Raycast` to the points, and evaluate against the previously created shape, you will get a mask.

   [image]
4. This mask is then used as a selection when applying the node `Instance on Points`.

   [image]

The result could then look something like this:

[image]

And from the camera's point of view, it looks something like this:

[image]

Here is the node group in overview:

[image]

And here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Man this is cool as hell. It's not quite what I need as I need the nearby shadows. So the gradient method allows shadows to appear in the render. Is it possible to make ANOTHER frustum that points toward an arbitrary point? (Like an empty or source of light) so objects are there to cast shadows.

Comment: @TheJeran I think this can be extended in this direction. Can you possibly visualize your question with a picture or a sketch so that I can better understand what exactly you mean?

Comment: @TheJeran btw: in this example you can change the dimensions of the frustum ...have you seen that?